# Correlation between Wiener and Orstein Ulenbeck processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, correlation, wiener-measure

Can anyone help me with finding correlation between:

$x(t)= W(t)$

and

$y(t) = \int_0^t \exp((s-t)a)dW(s), \quad ?$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= W(t)\\
&=\int_0^t dW(s).
\end{align*}
Then, by Ito's isometry,
\begin{align*}
E(x(t) y(t)) &= \int_0^t e^{(s-t)a}ds.
\end{align*}